# Include specific lines of code from a source file in Docusaurus

Tags: markdown, documentation-generation, docusaurus, file-inclusion

I'm currently deciding whether to migrate my developer docs from Sphinx to Docusaurus. The one thing that's holding me back is that Docusaurus (and in fact Markdown in general) doesn't support pulling specific lines of text from other files.

Sphinx (reStructuredText) allows you to `include` text between a `start-after` and `end-before` marker on another file - so really useful for pulling in code snips from fully functioning scripts:

```
.. include:: ./scripts/matts_script.py
   :start-after: # marker_1
   :end-before: # marker_2
```

So is there a way of doing this in Docusaurus? Has anyone done it? I'm thinking maybe levaraging MDX and JSX but that's really just a guess.